# Read other items in a python list while iterating through it

Tags: python, list, iterator

I use code like this to iterate through a list when I also need the next item in the list:

```
values = [1, 3, 6, 7 ,9]
diffs = []
for i in range(len(values)):
    try: diffs.append(values[i+1] - values[i])
    except: pass

print diffs
```

How can I simplify this?

gives:

```
[2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
for pos, item in enumerate(values):
    try:
        diffs.append(values[pos+1] - item)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

although in your case (since you're just looking for the next value), you could also simply use

```
for item,nextitem in zip(values, values[1:]):
    diffs.append(nextitem-item)
```

which can also be expressed as a list comprehension:

```
diffs = [nextitem-item for item,nextitem in zip(values, values[1:])]
```

Comment: deleted my earlier comment. If the list is longer than about 100 elements, then this is indeed cheaper than an `if`. So that's not 'very large' as I claimed was necessary for efficiency earlier. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> values = range(10)
>>> values
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> zip(values[0:],values[1:])
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: with `itertools.islice` for sufficiently large lists of course.

Comment: Although this works in this case, the  way to go for getting an item index and the  item is to use the "enumerate" generator - check @Tim Pietzcker's answer

Comment: @jsbueno -- true but irrelevant, the point is to pair up items in the list not to get an index over an iterable. @aaron: indeed!

Answer (score 2):

what about with the aid of [pairwise recipe from itertools document](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
def main():
    values = [1, 3, 6, 7 ,9]
    diffs = [post - prior for prior, post in pairwise(values)]
    print diffs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output
[2, 3, 1, 2]

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, j in zip(values, values[1:]):
     j - i
```

Comment: For big lists and Python 2.x, itertools.izip might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff = [values[i+1] - values[i] for i in range(len(values)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[y - x for x,y in zip(L,L[1:])]
```

Comment: you haven't seen previous answers, have you?